# Cant change <li> vertical position inside nav bar without affecting nav bar's size

Tags: html, css, nav

So I try to change li's vertical position but when I do the nav bar height is affected as well. What is the way to actually do that without affecting nav bar's height?

Here's the code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

ul li:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="kalli.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="mp.html">My Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="set.html">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you set a fixed height for the nav, it wont be affected of the height of the position of the li's

Comment: Okay I actually just changed li position to relative and placed it to -5px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your goal here? To have the content centered or...?

It may be better to use flexbox here rather than set the `padding-left: 850px;` on your ul (also on your `ul` you could've used `display: block; margin: 0 auto;` to center it.)  If you'd like, you can give your ul a defined height and use `align-items` to specify how it should be aligned vertically.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}


nav {
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
}
li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
ul li:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="kalli.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="mp.html">My Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="set.html">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `position: relative;` and a value for `bottom` or `top`- in my snippet `bottom: 4px;`:

This reserves the space originally taken by the element (without `position: relative;`), but moves the element according to the top/bottom/left/right settings, without affecting other elements.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 4px;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

ul li:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="kalli.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="mp.html">My Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="set.html">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
```